# browse-url: How to search the web for the keyword if the word under cursor (or selected) is not an URL?

Tags: web

The feature is more or less as the same as the navigation bar in most modern browsers: if it is a URL, load it; if not, use the default search engine to search the web for it. How can I achieve that in Emacs, such as modifying the default behavior of `browse-url`?

Comment: Shift k is pretty cool. I don't know if it just works on doom emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mostly does what you want:

```el
(defun my-search-or-browse ()
  "If selected region, or thing at point, is a url, go there. Otherwise,
use region/thing as a keyword for a google search."
  (interactive)
  (let ((target
         (if (use-region-p)
             (buffer-substring (region-beginning) (region-end))
           (thing-at-point 'symbol))))
    (if (ffap-url-p target)
        (browse-url target)
      (browse-url (concat "http://www.google.com/search?q="
                          (url-hexify-string target))))))
```

This will only recognize actual URLs, with the `http://` prefix. Plain addresses like `www.example.com` will be treated like keywords. I haven't found any built-in functions that would distinguish between actual urls of the form `google.com` and other strings with periods in them.

Comment: Just let you know that I also found [BrowseAproposURL](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseAproposURL).

Comment: @xuhdev Looks useful - maybe worth adding that as a separate answer!

Comment: New answer added!

Answer (score 1):

Some useful information are available at [BrowseAproposURL](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BrowseAproposURL) to address this issue. One important package is [keyword-search](https://github.com/keyword-search/keyword-search), which is available on MELPA. After installing the package, the command `keyword-search` will be available, which will search a keyword or visit the URL depending on the text.

Answer (score 1):

Another option which allows defining the search engine:

https://github.com/hrs/engine-mode

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this :

```
(defun px-websearch (start end)
  "Websearch selected string."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((q (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
    (browse-url (concat "https://qwant.com/?q="
                        (url-hexify-string q) "!g"))))
```